# Write bits in different bytes c c++

Tags: c++, c, bit

I have declared an array of bytes:

```
uint8_t memory[123];
```

which i have filled with:

```
memory[0]=0xFF;
memory[1]=0x00;
memory[2]=0xFF;
memory[3]=0x00;
memory[4]=0xFF;
```

And now i get requests from the user to write in certain bits. For example, the user provides the starting bit (ex:10), the amount of bits (ex:9) and what bits to set. In the example I provided I would receive 2 bytes:

```
setbit[0]=0b11110010;
setbit[1]=0b00000001; //padded with zeros for extra bits
```

This will be used for Modbus which is a big-endian protocol. I have come up with the following code:

```
for(int j=findByteINIT;j<(findByteFINAL);j++){

   aux[0]=(unsigned char) (setbit[j]>>(startingbit-(8*findByteINIT)));
   aux[1]=(unsigned char) (setbit[j+1]<<(startingbit-(8*findByteINIT)));

   memory[j]=(unsigned char) (aux[0] & memory[j] );
   memory[j+1]=(unsigned char) (aux[1] & memory[j+1] );


   aux[0]=0x00;//clean aux
   aux[1]=0x00;

        }
```

which does not work but should be close to the ideal solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why did you tag the question [tag:c], if your question is about C++? And can you explain more about what the _problem_ is? "does not work" doesn't tell us much about what you're struggling with.

Comment: Did you put 0b to show setbit is binary? Funny!

Comment: What's the question? And what does "does not work" mean? Where is bit 10? Are you counting right to left, or left to right? Do you start counting from 0 or 1? Sorry, I'm voting to close this as unclear... you must clarify your question.

Comment: show the definitions of `setbit` and `aux`

Comment: This question seems the same as your previous question, just with slightly different input. You can use the answer to the previous question by simply converting between the kinds of input. I've updated my answer to the previous question to cover this conversion.

Comment: @bames53 that is not the case. Now i receive bytes to modify the memory! in the example i provided i receive setbits[0], setbits[1], the starting bit and the amount of bits to modify, and i must modify the corresponding memory area! –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work. However I've only tested it lightly.

```
  int start_bit = 10; int bit_count = 9;
  uint8_t setbit[2] = { 0b11110010, 0b00000001 };

  int setbit_size = (bit_count + (CHAR_BIT - 1)) / CHAR_BIT;

  int start_byte = start_bit / CHAR_BIT;
  int shift = start_bit % CHAR_BIT;
  int modified_bytes =
      bit_count ? (bit_count + shift + (CHAR_BIT - 1)) / CHAR_BIT : 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < modified_bytes; ++i) {
    uint8_t mask = 0xFF;
    if (i == 0) {
      mask <<= shift;
    } else if (i == modified_bytes - 1) {
      mask >>= CHAR_BIT - (bit_count + shift) % CHAR_BIT;
    }

    uint8_t carried = i > 0 ? (setbit[i - 1] >> (CHAR_BIT - shift)) : 0;
    uint8_t added = i < setbit_size ? static_cast<uint8_t>(setbit[i] << shift) : 0;
    memory[start_byte + i] =
        (memory[start_byte + i] & ~mask) | ((carried | added) & mask);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these macros.

```
#define ISBITARRAYSET(b,arr)      (((arr)[(b)/8]&(1<<((b)%8)))==0?FALSE:TRUE)
#define ISBITARRAYCLR(b,arr)      (((arr)[(b)/8]&(1<<((b)%8)))==0?TRUE:FALSE)
#define SETBITARRAY(b,arr)        ((arr)[(b)/8]|= (1<<((b)%8)))
#define CLRBITARRAY(b,arr)        ((arr)[(b)/8]&= ~(1<<((b)%8)))
```

Example:

```
#define BIT10 0x0A;

    if( ISBITARRAYCLR(BIT10,myarray) )
    {
        SETBITARRAY(BIT10,myarray);
    }
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Should be close to an ideal solution, but

1) Probably you meant to shift left, followed by a shift right for the remaining bits

```
aux[0] = setbit[j] << (startingbit-(8*findByteINIT))
aux[1] = setbit[j] >> (8 - (startingbit-(8*findByteINIT)))
```

if startingbit is 10, I suspect findByteINIT would become 1, so

```
startingbit-(8*findByteINIT)     ==  2
0b11110010 << 2    ==   0b11001000
```

and aux[1] :

```
8 - (startingbit-(8*findByteINIT))     ==  6
0b11110010 >> 6    ===  0b00000011
```

together with the 8 bits skipped with findByteINIT :

```
   aux[1]    aux[0]   skipped
0b 000000011 11001000 00000000 
                  ^  11110010 starting at bit 10
```

2) the 0b prefix is not standard, it is not much portable

3) if you meant to set the bits, use or instead of and.

```
  memory[j]=(unsigned char) (aux[0] | memory[j] );
  // (aux[0] & memory[j] )  just clears the bits of memory[j] not set in aux[0]
  // also, shorter form:
  memory[j] |= aux[0];
```

Comment: The `0b` prefix has been formally added to the standard in C++14.